# View endpoint in glassfish is not visible when webservices project created using intellij

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I am quite new to Java EE and as my first project I created a webservices project in Intellij according to the method described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-web-service-client-development-support-through-a-dedicated-facet.html). When I run the project and deployed it using glassfish and viewed the application in http://localhost:4848/ I can't see *view endpoint* link in the grid Modules and Components when I had clicked on the app I deployed. Any idea what might be wrong with my methods?

Answer (score 0):

Dose your web-service in the default package ?
I have came across with same issue, and as i passed the web service to custom package and redeployed it ,the view endpoint appeared..

Comment: What do you mean default vs. custom package?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today but I use Eclipse Oxygen and Glassfish 5.0 with JDK1.8.0_151 : It miss last line in the array at the bottom of this screenshot :

[image]

After a lot of search and tests, I found a blog ( http://meveekay.blogspot.fr/2016/09/view-endpoint-is-not-available-on.html ) that propose the content of the following file :

WEB-INF/web.xml

In fact, you have just to replace the older content by a more recent.

**Explaination** :

**Situation 1** : When I open a new Maven project from Eclipse Oxygen based on archetype "webapp"; the project contains an older web.xml. The content use again DTD for  declaration.

[image: Create new Maven project (m2e) from Eclipse Oxygen with webap archetype]

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**Situation 2** : When I open a new JavaEE project from Eclipse Oxygen, the web.xml content use XML schema for  declaration.

Finally the good web.xml content for today is this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

After "mvn clean install" to regenerate war file, redeploy it and constat the line with "View Endpoint" link appear ... Enjoy !!!

[image]